# Spring постраничный вывод из БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, pagination

Есть небольшое CRUD приложение. Подскажите как лучше реализовать постраничный вывод данных из БД? 
Контролер:

```
@Controller
public class PartController {
    private PartService partService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "partService")
    public void setBookService(PartService partService) {
        this.partService = partService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "parts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listBooks(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("part", new Part());
        model.addAttribute("listParts", this.partService.listParts());

        return "parts";
    }
```

DAO:

```
public interface PartDao {
    void addPart(Part part);
    void updatePart(Part part);
    void removePart(Long id);
    Part getPartById(Long id);
    List<Part> listParts();
}

public class PartDaoImpl implements PartDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPart(Part part) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(part);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePart(Part part) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(part);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePart(Long id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Part part = session.load(Part.class, id);
        if (part != null)
            session.delete(part);
    }

    @Override
    public Part getPartById(Long id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Part.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Part> listParts() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Part> partList = session.createQuery("from Part").list();
        return partList;
    }

}
```

И сама страница:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Склад запчастей</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Список комплектующих</h1>

<c:if test="${!empty listParts}">
    <table align="center" class="tg" >
        <tr>
            <th width="250">Название</th>
            <th width="120">Необходимость</th>
            <th width="120">Количество</th>
            <th width="60">Править</th>
            <th width="60">Удалить</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listParts}" var="part">
            <tr>
                <td>${part.name}</td>
                <td align="center">${part.must}</td>
                <td align="center">${part.count}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${part.id}'/>">Править</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${part.id}'/>">Удалить</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `List<Part> listParts(int skip, int take)`

Comment: можно подробнее?

Comment: Пользуйтесь Spring Data JPA. Там можно лиюдо в параметр метода передавать объект PageRequest, что и будет являться паджинацией элементов.

Comment: @R1zen, формируйте запрос (конкретика зависит от СУБД/ORM), который будет ограничен некоторым смещением и размером. Для MySQL будет что-то вроде `SELECT column FROM table LIMIT page_size OFFSET page_size * (page_no - 1);`. Зная размер страницы (количество элементов) и ее номер из этого можно найти элементы с определенной страницы. Ну или готовые реализации, вроде предложенной выше.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать множество методов [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html)

```
public interface NoteRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Note, Long> {
    List<Note> findByIsDone(Boolean isDone);
    Note findById(long id);
    Page<Note> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Note> findAllByIsDone(Pageable pageable, Boolean isDone);
}
```

Ну и в контроллере или в отдельном классе вспомогательный метод типа

```
 private Model getPaginateModel(int countForPage, int quantityOfNotesPerPage,  Model model) {
    Iterable<Note> notes;
    Pageable sizeOfPage = PageRequest.of(countForPage, quantityOfNotesPerPage, Direction.ASC, "date"); 
    Page<Note> notePage = noteRepo.findAllByIsDone(sizeOfPage, true);
    notes = notePage.getContent();
    model.addAttribute("notes", notes);
    return model;
}
```

Здесь частный случай, выбираются выполненные заметки, сортируются по возрастанию даты "date", можно на вход методу подать любые параметры сортировки, или фильтрации и, соответственно, реализовать любую модель постраничного вывода.